# Why don't Stack Overflow users use their brains to bag the hard-to-find information and vote down/close questions for wrong or missing details?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, downvotes

I see a common problem at Stack Overflow that users normally downvote the question or vote to close it without helping the OP to make it more appropriate or answerable.

I have seen many questions which would be solved with just one inaccurate Google search, but they have hundreds of upvotes and questions with hard-to-find answers are closed or downvoted because OP was not able to describe it properly.

I think everyone should first assume that OP may have tried his best to describe the question, but could not think on the missing or incorrect part, and it would be more better to give a comment and mention what OP needs to change or add in the question to make it answerable rather than downvoting and commenting that what is wrong in the question.

What I really want is, if you want to contribute here, then mention the solution, not the problem. And if you can then edit the question so that it can be answerable.

Comment: Why SO posters don't use brain to make the question better so SO users don't have to do it for them? SO users give their time away for free to solve the problems the SO posters are having. It's not our problem; why should we have to do the work to both *ask* the question and then *answer* the question? People posting questions are already asking us to donate free time (and knowledge) to solve their problem for them, and now you're asking us to donate more free time to actually write the question as well. Can we come to your office and copy/paste or type too and pay for our own travel?

Comment: I know the importance of time and have been contributing in google group when SO was not popular. But why SO users give their time for free? Not because they are king of their domain and don't have time but because they like to help others and learn more in doing so. Means SO users learn and get experience in solving variety of real world problems for free by solving the question posted by SO posters.

Comment: If a topic is good then its worthy to correct the question. Do you know why justice is manged by police because if a revolver is given to everyone to secure the law then no one will live to break the law. So keep patience and if you can help then help else don't punish SO posters for being beginners, newbie or poor in describing their problem.

Comment: @SandeepKumar The up/down votes are an indicator of whether a question is good. But you want to eliminate down votes and get people to polish the turd until it is good - unfortunately that is not an option for many questions we get.

Comment: Yes I agree and that's why I mentioned this for good topics or for problems with hard to find answers. I did not mentioned or want to eliminate down votes they are extremely required for the purpose they created. What I want is to reduce aggressive voting because it is preventing the addition of complex scenario with proper details and promoting the common scenario or say easily solvable scenario to clutter the SO.

Comment: There is the Help and Improvement queue for users with enough reputation, which is exactly for making the questions better. But they are usually so badly formulated, that there is no way anyone could make them better. And it is not a good thing to *assume* or *guess* what the OP meant. Also, I haven't seen downvoting on questions that would actually have some substance to them. Usually there are comments asking for clarifications. Downvotes usually happen when the question is of the type "I want to program and have an error plz help kthxbai."

Comment: no, I will downvote any post that is lacking and flag for closing anything that is outside the rules. End of Story.

Comment: *why SO users give their time for free?* You're right. It's because we like to help others. If it takes me 10 minutes to research a bad question so that I can improve it enough to be useful, and then take 10 more minutes to write an answer to (now my own) question, I could have spent that same 20 minutes helping two or three other users who were willing to do that basic research and provide it in their questions themselves. As I said before, do you want us to travel to their site to personally babysit too? Maybe serve them coffee and doughnuts while we're at it, and bring lunch? Help yourself.

Comment: You want to fix them? Go right ahead. I hereby appoint you my representative; you can *personally* spend all of your free time researching all of the bad questions here, locate that hard to find information, and rewrite all of those extremely low quality posts into something we can answer. I'd offer to pay you for it, but we all know that you wouldn't accept it anyway, because you just *love* giving away all of your time for free to help others that aren't willing to even try to help themselves.

Comment: And, in case anyone forgot to mention it, **SO works because people downvote bad questions and upvote good questions**. That's **exactly** how the entire site was designed to work from the day Jeff and Joel decided to create it. Didn't you ever take the [tour] (I know you did - you checked the box that said so when you created your account, right?) or read the *Our Model* pages in the [help]?

Answer (score 18):

Let's take a look at some questions that are open right now. Feel free to provide the information needed to fix these:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30250845

> I write an ios bluetooth file transfer program by writting data to the device constantly. However, the speed of the transfer is about 1.5kb/s. It is so slow and who can tell why?

How does anyone other than the OP fix this? I have no idea what's wrong with this user's program. They have provided no code, no method of replication, nothing other than "it is so slow". Please tell him why it's slow...

Someone was nice enough and commented that more information was needed. Since that's there, am I allowed to down vote and vote to close now?

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30251021

> I want to create timelaps video with selfie images. and the main problem is all selfie images should be same position.Please help how to create image with custom position and custom angle?

Great. Someone is motivated to build an application. Will you provide them with all the code they need to their specifications?

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30251073/

> I need an asm program for ATmega128 that counts the "one"-s on the B port and on the C port the proper bit will be one depending on the B. For example: If I have three 1-s on the B port, on the C port the 3rd bit will be one. If there isn't any "one"-s on the B port, all the bits in the C port remain zero.

I need a pony. But, that's not relevant here. The problem with this question is that there isn't a question. It's a list of demands. Or, it's a very impolite request for someone to write an entire program for them.

---

The problem with these, and countless others, is that they are either questions that don't contain nearly enough information for others to answer or they are simply demands for others to do the work.

In the first case, it is not uncommon to see comments requesting more information. But, it's also common for such a question to be closed and within those close reasons users are given feedback. For example, if there is no code provided (like the first example) a valid close reason:

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

That's pretty clear that the OP needs to make some changes. Once they edit it to contain all the information, the question can be reopened.

A request (or demand) for code or an entire program sounds like a job. Stack Overflow is filled with users that *volunteer* their time to help others. We aren't here to do your job (or homework). We are here to help you get answers. More importantly, we are here to help the person behind you that has the same question, but has it a year from now. A simple demand for code isn't going to accomplish either of those goals.

> [I]f you want to contribute here then mention the solution not the problem.

Sometimes the solution is to inform the user that they aren't using the site correctly. Encouraging them to provide all the information so that their question can be answered is a start. Encouraging them to *ask* a question and not issue a demand is another good start.

Downvotes/close votes/flags are all signals to the asker that something is wrong with their post.

Comment: The question "Why is the speed of bluetooth file transfer so slow in my app?" is incomplete so the comment is incomplete. Did you noticed the OP is new user but who tried to help and comment has score of 1k but still incomplete comment. He should have mentioned as you did here in answer "I have no idea what's wrong with this program, share your code and steps to replicate your problem".

Comment: And for the TOPIC of question I don't think its a very common for every one to write a good program for bluetooth file transfer in ios. And OP has done something he is not lazy but he is not experienced with SO or don't have good skill in describing his problem so in start need guidance in that too. This is what I mentioned why SO users don't use their brain.

Comment: The question "how to create image with custom position and custom angle?" got 2 down votes but why? He is a new user and if some one thinks that doing down vote is his right then informing him what needs to be correct in the question should be his responsibility before down voting.

Comment: The last question "Assemby program on ATmega128" as usual a student asking others to do his homework and new to SO but get good comments and now he knows what he has done wrong.

Comment: Now for your shared example, its right to vote close but before that give him comment on what he need to do to keep the question open. You know the rules may be he not and for new users surely they don't know the rules.

Comment: Doing down votes and close votes force the OP to avoid posting questions and answers where as guiding them about things to correct in their question or answer is encouraging them to contribute more and grow SO user community.

Comment: No one is forcing anyone to do anything other than to abide by the quality rules of Stack Overflow, if they don't like it, the Internet is a big place...

Comment: @santiago: Sorry, that was meant to be to him - fail on autocomplete due to multiple "san" :) Will delete and repost...

Comment: @SandeepKumar: "Doing down votes and close votes force the OP to avoid posting questions and answers" - absolutely not. It forces the OP to avoid posting bad questions and answers. There's plenty of information available about how to post good questions and answers, including the information shown to the user before they first post a question at all.

Comment: @SandeepKumar: We *want* the OP to avoid posting bad questions and write good ones instead. This is not a babysitting service, where our job is to hold your hand and baby you through learning how things work. There is a lot of information available to new users about how to ask questions here, as well as a whole lot of good examples of how to do so. We have plenty of traffic from users who are actually eager to learn and get a solution to their problem and are willing to ask a decent question to do so.

Answer (score 8):

> I think Everyone should first assume that OP may have tried his best to describe the question....

There is a saying: *Never assume anything because it makes an ass out of you and me...*. The assumption you made is bad, very bad.

> What I really want is, if you want to contribute here then mention the solution not the problem.

This is also a bad option. Specific problems usually have reasonably specific solutions. Solutions by themselves could have 10's or 100's of possible approaches.

Think of it this way: Stack Overflow allows you to state your desired solution, but also demands that you state your current approach (the "problem"). This way a specific answer can usually be arrived at that satisfies the current problem and the desired solution, rather than answerers guessing and throwing dozens of possible approaches at the OP.

**Edit:**

Due to your comment and the tags you've used, I guess your real question is:

> Why not force people to fix a question instead of down voting it?

That (and variations on it) has been covered probably thousands of times already here, so I'm not going to give it more oxygen.

Comment: "Solutions by themselves could have 10's or 100's of possible approaches." means not answerable with current description. Then mention the OP what he needs to change/add in question. "What I really want is, if you want to contribute here then mention the solution not the problem." This line don't say to post answer but comment with direction for OP to make his question appropriate. Overall if topic or question is good then help the OP to ask the question correctly and then answer it.
Voting down or close is stopping the valuable information from being part of SO encyclopedia

Comment: Being aggressive is so much easy but keeping calm and helping the needy is what distinguish human from animals.

Comment: You haven't learned yet that there are the needy, then there are those who are too lazy or stupid to help themselves. I have time for one of those but not the other, and unfortunately one of those vastly outnumbers the other.

Comment: Will you like your boss to angry on you because of problem caused by others? No, no one will like it. People who are lazy or stupid to help themselves mostly need help in common situations which are easily available using google but not in complex scenarios which are hard to get using google. And assume if they have asked any question in complex scenario then within 1-2 comments with suggestion or points it can be determined if are they really trying to solve the problem or not.

Comment: I don't know how valuable or precious your time is, but to me my time is both. I find it insulting that you think that everyone is **automatically entitled** to an answer from the busy professionals on this site. I don't care how angry their boss is - lazy and/or stupid people shouldn't be programming. How angry do you think my boss would be if I started spending lots of time coaching lazy useless programmers in how to ask a decent question that has all the relevant information? I also think this current discussion is going nowhere and it's time it stopped....